# Using of MotionEvent (ACTION_MOVE)

Tags: android, motionevent

So I have special question to you:
How can I catch buttons when I use move action? How can I handle moves on my screen for buttons(or other elements)?

I used MotionEvent (ACTION_MOVE) but by using that fragment of code i don't get the desired result

in OnCreate

```
btn1.setOnTouchListener(this); //for all of buttons on Activity
```

in onTouch

```
switch(event.getAction()) { 
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 
       //actions
  break;
}
```

actions will be occur for first button from which the movement starts. In other case nothing will occur

At this time I think that I can use ACTION_MOVE for my Activity not for each button or other elements and save coordinates of buttons(top left and bottom right) to arraylist.
And when movement starts I could compare this coordinates and real coordinates of movement.
So by that way I could know on which buttons movement was.

Probably I reinvent the wheel. That why I ask for your help)

Comment: I am sorry, I see strings of words but this just doesn't make sense. You want to use button coördinates to create drag and drop? What?

Comment: no, I don't need drag and drop(sorry for my bad English), I just want to know what buttons was touched by single movement and handle this action for all of them. 
Hope, that now you understand what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you explain more clear? From what I see you need probably do two things: 
First add listener to all buttons and let your activity implement onTouchListener.
Second you need to save initial coordinate for each button in MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN(if I'm right about syntax).
This way you will have access to all buttons of yours and you can save their coordinates correctly

Comment: from above in comment

Comment: You can get your button ID when the Touch happens so you will be Okay I guess.

Comment: so that way I take only first touched by movement button id, not all
(I added ids to HashSet)

Comment: Well if I'm not making a mistake I have a good idea of what you should do, you can loop through all of your buttons (you should save a reference to them before in an array or set or something) in your onTouch and get their coordinates using btnx.getX() & btnx.getY() this way when one of them moves you will move others and save their coordinates.

Comment: how I can add there a picture to show you what I do?

Comment: you can't add pic now because you have low rep, you can mail me though, use this address: erfan.molaei@gmail.com I'll solve your problem :)

Comment: did you get my message?

Comment: yup, wait a moment :)

Answer (score 0):

You will get the view inside the touch listener, using which you can identify.

```
Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);

btn1.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
btn2.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
btn3.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);

private OnTouchListener touchListener = new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn1:
                //Button 1
                break;

            case R.id.btn2:
                //Button 2
                break;

            case R.id.btn3:
                //Button 3
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: but this correctly works only to first moved button(and if movement starts from it), not for all, where movement occurs. And I don't add cases because there is one action to handle motion action for all buttons